# complex numbers - roots and modulus

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $z$ and $w$ be two complex numbers such that 
$z\overline{z} - w\bar{w}=r$ for some real number $r$.
Can we conclude that $z$ and $w$ are real numbers if
$$(z^2-w^2)\left(\overline{\sqrt{z^2-w^2}}\right)^2=r^2. $$
$\overline{\sqrt{z^2-w^2}}$ is the complex conjugate of $\sqrt{z^2-w^2}$ which is
$\sqrt{\bar{z}^2-\bar{w}^2}$. I wrote it in this form because I didn't want to confuse real absolute value with a complex modulus. 
Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by the square-root?

Comment: Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$ then $z= re^{i\alpha}$ for some angle $\alpha \in [-\pi, \pi]$ and radious $r \geq 0$. We define $\sqrt{z}:= \sqrt{r}e^{i \alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly question, so I will write the answer. If you take $z=2i$ and $w=i$, then
$ |z|^2 = 4, |w|^2=1$ and $z\bar{z}-w\bar{w}=4-1=3$.
Moreover,

$z^2-w^2=-3$ and $\sqrt{z^2-w^2}=\pm i\sqrt{3} $, so $\overline{\sqrt{z^2-w^2}}=\mp i \sqrt{3}$ and $\left(\overline{\sqrt{z^2-w^2}}\right)^2 = -3$. Thus,

$(z^2-w^2)\left(\overline{\sqrt{z^2-w^2}}\right)^2=(-3)(-3)=9$.
So the assumptionns are satisfied, but neither $z$ nor $w$ are real numbers.